# being raised in a copper’s home

Tags: meaning

I am reading a police novel and I can't understand the sentence "Something rubbed off being raised in a copper’s home.” A policeman talks to a journalist. His daughter is a reporter too. She made a discovery (his father helped her) about the crime and "beated the journalist to the punch".

“Rather than you admit she beat you to the punch?” -- the policeman said.
“Because she’s your daughter and had inside knowledge,” the journalist argued.
“What can I say? Something rubbed off being raised in a copper’s home.”

Comment: What do you not understand?

Answer (score 1):

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rub-off) says about the phrase ***to rub off***:

> If a quality or characteristic that someone has *rubs off*, other **people begin to have it because they have been with that person and learned it from them**:
>
> - His enthusiasm is starting to *rub off* on the rest of us.

As for ***copper***, it is slang for ***policeman***:

> ***Cop, Coppa or Copper***
> The term *copper* was the original, word, originally used in Britain to mean "someone who captures". In British English, the term *cop* is recorded (Shorter Oxford Dictionary) in the sense of 'to capture' from 1704, derived from the Latin *capere* via the Old French caper.
> The OED suggests that "*copper*" is from "*cop*" in this sense, but adds that the derivation is uncertain. Many imaginative but incorrect stories have come up over the years, including that *cop* refers to the police uniform's copper buttons, the police man's copper badge, or that it is an abbreviation for "constable on patrol", "constabulary of police", or "chief of police". ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_police-related_slang_terms))

So basically,

> Something rubbed off being raised in a copper’s home.

means that if you are raised in a cop's home, it is only natural to have acquired the skills of a cop.

Comment: I think that *cop* is slang for *copper* rather than the other way round.

Comment: Yes, "cop" is actually slang itself. I have edited.